# Select top in SQL nvarchar instead of int

Tags: sql-server

I tried to use a select statement with top value in parameter like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_TOP @NUM INT AS
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(255) = 'SELECT TOP ' + @NUM + ' * FROM MYTABLE;'
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

It return me an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT TOP ' to
>   data type int.

But when i change from `int` to `nvarchar` its work:

```
PROC_TOP @NUM nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(255)
```

My Question is:

Why Sql accept the datatype `nvarchar` instead of `Int`?

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(255) = 'SELECT TOP ' + cast(@NUM as varchar(6)) + ' * FROM MYTABLE;'
```

Comment: This is work if DECLARE SQL VARCHAR(255) change to DECLARE SQL NVARCHAR(255).. thanks –

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation with + will not do datatype conversion, If you use concat it will do datatype conversion implicitly as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_TOP @NUM INT AS
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(255) = concat('SELECT TOP ' , @NUM , ' * FROM MYTABLE;')
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

Comment: Why? Which version of sql server?

Comment: I am using 2008.. I have upvoted your post but i think somebody downvoted on it.